# Azure Function App Python terminates after a while

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am using a blob trigger with a python function on an Azure functions app with the consumption plan. I know it is in preview but it is a bummer that the app terminates after a while of no usage. And it will not get back to live when a new blob is added.

The function works perfectly locally

Is there a way to keep the function app alive?

Comment: FYI, this is called a "cold start", see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/. So your instance will take longer to process the blob if it was in an inactive state. To fix that, you can use the "dedicated" plan instead of "consumption" which will keep your app alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the right way to do it but I added a second http trigger function to start the app and that works. So my current process is: trigger the http function and then upload the blob.

I also tried a cron trigger but that also didn't fire.